# Why can't the cupy installation process detect Microsoft Visual C++?

Tags: installation, python-3.8, cupy

I am currently trying to install the latest version of cupy (cupy-8.0.0b4.tar.gz) using the asset on the releases page, but when I try to install the module on my MSI (Windows 10) with a NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060 graphics card after installing the CUDA Toolkit (version 11.0.2), Python 3.8, and the package Cython and numpy, I see the following error:

```
building 'cupy.core._carray' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.2 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\mjim2\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\mjim2\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-z9h9y2dz\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\mjim2\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-z9h9y2dz\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\mjim2\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-c5iitjqj\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\mjim2\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Include\cupy' Check the logs for full command output.
---
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\___\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 827, in install
    success = install_legacy(
  File "c:\users\___\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\install\legacy.py", line 86, in install
    raise LegacyInstallFailure
pip._internal.operations.install.legacy.LegacyInstallFailure

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\___\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 188, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\___\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 185, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "c:\users\___\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 398, in run
    installed = install_given_reqs(
  File "c:\users\___\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\__init__.py", line 67, in install_given_reqs
    requirement.install(
  File "c:\users\___\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 845, in install
    six.reraise(*exc.parent)
  File "c:\users\___\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\six.py", line 703, in reraise
    raise value
  File "c:\users\___\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\install\legacy.py", line 74, in install
    runner(
  File "c:\users\___\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\subprocess.py", line 270, in runner
    call_subprocess(
  File "c:\users\___\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\subprocess.py", line 241, in call_subprocess
    raise InstallationError(exc_msg)
```

I have Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable (x86) - 14.26.28720 installed, but the program cannot seem to detect the software. I'm having difficulty deciphering the source of the exception. I need to figure out how I can hardcode the folder location of the program into the python code or if there is another problem I should be looking at instead. If anyone can help me here, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Are the paths to everything in your PATH variable?

Comment: I would think so; my system was able to detect CUDA. What would be the path to the C++ package, if that would need to be an environment variable?

Comment: Try seeing if the Developer command line was installed along with the C++ tools. From there you can find the path to the executable for the developer command line, and then find the bin folder containing cl.exe. Then add that path to your path.

Comment: Alright, I've done that, and am now able to run cl from the command line, but I got the same error detailed above. :(

Answer (score 0):

"Visual C++ Redistributable" is a runtime library. If you need to build CuPy from source, you need to install the VC++ compiler from the URL shown in the error message.

Comment: I have installed the Visual Installer and downloaded Visual Studio Professional, Visual Studio Community, and Visual Studio Build Tools 2019. For each of them, I have installed the ""Desktop development with C++" and "C++ build tools" with the following additions: MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools (v14.26),
Windows 10 SDK (10.0.18362.0),
C++ CMake tools for Windows,
Testing tools core features - Build Tools,
C++ AddressSanitizer (Experimental).
I haven't gotten much progress despite these installations, I feel like I have to explicitly state a reference in some way.

Comment: Exactly which download should I download from the link?

Comment: Please try following instructions on Python's website: `https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers#Microsoft_Visual_C.2B-.2B-_14.2_standalone:_Build_Tools_for_Visual_Studio_2019_.28x86.2C_x64.2C_ARM.2C_ARM64.29`

Comment: I have followed the instructions, reinstalling Visual Build Tools and getting the required packages, yet the same error still stands. I have looked up the PATH that Arvin Kushwaha suggested through the Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019 and added it to my existing PATH, without success. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Try updating setuptools and pip. `python -m pip install -U setuptools pip`

Comment: The command just tells me that both of these packages have their requirements already fulfilled.